# What is the difference between a url with a www and one without the www

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I created a website in wordpress the link is

`flyrenegadeair.com`
When you type the link on any browser it opens this

```
https://flyrenegadeair.com
```

which opens the home page to the website.

When you instead type

```
www.flyrenegadeair.com
```

it gives 404 error.

I have tried all manner of redirects nothing seems to get the link with `www` to work.

Is there a way to redirect the `www` link to the `non-www` ?

here is the .htaccess code

```
# Remove header with PHP version
Header always unset X-Powered-By
Header unset X-Powered-By
# END Security Block
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.flyrenegadeair.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://flyrenegadeair.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (.htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise maybe you need to clear the cache or try with another browser. if needed try with another device.
make sure the address of .htaccess file is true and it is accessible.
change file permission to 644 and then try again.

Second way for redirecting http to https requests. replace it with the last four lines of your code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have added the .htaccess codes as they were

I dont usually do any coding so i may not know where to add the snippet you sent

Comment: so now try second way which I have added.